# php mysql sql injection execute delete

Tags: php, mysql

If there is a query via a php script which is vulnerable like

```
select email from mytable where id = $_REQUEST['id']
```

Is there a risk that someone can execute a truncate table etc using sql vulnerability.

This query is executed using mysql_query(). Multi queries are not allowed.

I understand that this is a vulnerable code. What I  want to know is if someone can execute a delete or truncate. I want to know the extent of the vulnerability

Comment: Are you display the query at front end?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: yes, thera are vulnerabities. you need to escape your variables.

Answer (score 1):

sure if you let user to fill the "id" freely.

for example:

`$_REQUEST['id'] = 123; delete from mytable where 1;
select email from mytable where id = 123; delete from mytable where 1;`

and if you use `multi_query()` then the second query will be executed.

Comment: I am using mysql_query() for the execution. Multi queries are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is not a correct way to execute queries. Lets check this following example of simple SQL Injection

```
<?php
// We didn't check $_POST['password'], it could be anything the user wanted! For example:
$_POST['username'] = 'aidan';
$_POST['password'] = "' OR ''='";

// Query database to check if there are any matching users
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='{$_POST['username']}' AND   password='{$_POST['password']}'";
mysql_query($query);

// This means the query sent to MySQL would be:
echo $query;
?>
```

The query sent to MySQL

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE user='aidan' AND password='' OR ''=''`

Always use `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very vulnerable to sql injection.

**Use prepared statements and parameterized queries.**

Using mysqli_, the right way to do is like this:

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT email FROM mytable WHERE id = ?');

$stmt->bind_param('s', $_REQUEST['id']);

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do whatever you need with $row
}
```

You can also use prepared statements with PDO